# regex help - php

Tags: regex

```
$data = "<Data>hello</Data>";
preg_match_all("/\<Data\>[.]+\<\/Data\>/", $data, $match);
print_r($match);
```

This returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

So I am guessing that a match is not made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("#<Data>.+</Data>#", $data, $match);
```

If you wanted to use / as the delimiter:

```
preg_match_all("/<Data>.+<\/Data>/", $data, $match);
```

The main problem was that a `.` inside a character class matches a literal period.  Also, using a different delimiter eliminates escaping.  Note that you don't have to escape `<` either way.  If you want to be able to extract the inner value, use:

```
preg_match_all("#<Data>(.+)</Data>#", $data, $match);
```

"hello" will now be in `$matches[1]` in your example.  Note that regex is not suited for parsing XML, so switch to a real parser for anything non-trivial.

Comment: Wow, thanks Matthew.  

What does the "#" stand for?  In all my php regex I have always began and ended with "/" in the past...

Comment: PHP allows you to use any delimiter at the beginning and end of a regex, which is convenient because it minimizes escaping.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the [] and . incorrectly.

Try this :

```
$data = "<Data>hello</Data>";
preg_match_all("/\<Data\>.+\<\/Data\>/", $data, $match);
print_r($match);
```

When you use the [] your a defining a list of possible caracter, in your case the caracters you defined where limited to . only. If you want to use the . to define any caracter you have to use it outside of [].

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$data = "<Data>hello</Data>";
preg_match_all('#<Data>(.+)</Data>#', $data, $match);
print_r($match);

?>
```

The output: ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/TcgYX))

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <Data>hello</Data>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
        )

)
```

`[...]` is a character class definition. You use `(...)` to capture.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

#### Special note on reluctant matching

Since you're using `preg_match_all`, it should be noted that you're currently matching greedily. That is, there is only one match in, say, `<Data>hello</Data><Data>how are you</Data>` ([see on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/PUy7T)).

If you want both `<Data>` elements, then you must use reluctant matching `'#<Data>(.+?)</Data>#'` ([see on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/OTQNi)).

To illustrate:

```
----A--Z----A----Z----
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        A.*Z
```

There is only one `A.*Z` match in the above input.

---

#### Special note on regex to parse HTML/XML

It's a pain. If at all possible, use a proper HTML/XML parser. There are plenty for PHP.

Comment: +1 for suggesting use of capturing (which is almost certainly the intent).

Answer (score 1):

Inside character classes a dot is just a dot.

```
<?php  

    $data = "<Data>hello</Data>";
    preg_match_all("/\<Data\>.+\<\/Data\>/", $data, $match);
    print_r($match);

?>
```

Will yield:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <Data>hello</Data>
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you dont need the brackets around the .

```
"/\<Data\>.+\<\/Data\>/"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/<Data>([^<^>]+)\<\/Data\>/

$data = "<Data>hello</Data>";
preg_match_all("/<Data>([^<^>]+)\<\/Data\>/", $data, $match);

print_r($match);
```